# Dynamically create frame on combo box selection (& button click )

Tags: php, javascript, html, combobox

I am developing a website in PHP where for e.g there's a menu on the left side containing list of "Food Products" - Vegetables, Fruits, Pulses, etc. On Clicking "Vegetables", another menu appears on left side containing list of veg. - Potatoes, Carrot, etc.
All this content can be added or modified only by admin.

I am thinking of adding a facility where in the admin login will have  **Combobox1** (populated with vegetables,fruits,..), 
**Combobox2** (populated with list of veg's on selection of vegetables from cmb1) and a **Browse** button which will select a doc file and when i click on the "**upload**" button, a frame/web page will be created dynamically and the contents of word doc will be displayed on that web page.

Can anyone suggest me as to how to proceed with this?

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: use jQuery to manipulate DOM and AJAX to make requests.

Comment: @webbandit : thanks for ur quick response.. can u explain in more detail?

Answer (score 1):

1. You have only 1 Combobox (`Combo1` - is combobox with "Food Types") on the screen, nothing is selected. Second combobox (`Combo2` - list of products belongs to the same type) is disabled.
2. User selects option from `Combo1`. AJAX request is sent to server (sending Food Type). Server responses with list of products belongs to Food Type.
3. You get the response making response items options of `Combo2` using jQuery. Then you make `Combo2` avaliable so user can pick any option and submit the form.